# MySQL using AND OR conditionals

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, conditional-statements

I have a table with columns homeTeamId, and visitorTeamId.

I want to display the rows where homeTeamId = 39 or 43 AND visitorTeamId = 39 or 43

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM game WHERE (homeTeamId='$_GET[homeTeamId]' or '$_GET[visitorTeamId]' and visitorTeamId='$_GET[homeTeamId]' or '$_GET[visitorTeamId]')";
```

gives me

```
homeTeamName    visitorTeamName visitorTeamId   homeTeamId  visitorTeamScore    homeTeamScore   date

barrard teamName0   39  43  0   0   2016 01/17 09:41 pm
teamName0   barrard 43  39  0   0   2016 01/17 10:18 pm
teamName0   barrard 43  39  0   0   2016 01/17 10:26 pm
```

however, if i use something like 39 and 20 i get the exact same results.

i tried this way

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM game WHERE homeTeamId=('$_GET[homeTeamId]' or '$_GET[visitorTeamId]') and visitorTeamId=('$_GET[homeTeamId]' or '$_GET[visitorTeamId]')";
```

and i get no result,

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `WHERE homeTeamId IN (39,43) OR visitorTeamId IN (39, 43)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM game WHERE 
(homeTeamId='$_GET[homeTeamId]' OR homeTeamId='$_GET[visitorTeamId]')
AND 
(visitorTeamId='$_GET[homeTeamId]' OR visitorTeamId='$_GET[visitorTeamId]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM game WHERE (homeTeamId='$_GET[homeTeamId]' OR homeTeamId='$_GET[visitorTeamId]') AND (visitorTeamId='$_GET[homeTeamId]' OR visitorTeamId'$_GET[visitorTeamId]')";
```

Or use shorter aproach [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), posted as comment under your post!
Using IN, you can realize even more complex queries.

Using in:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE homeTeamId IN ('$_GET[homeTeamId]', 
       '$_GET[visitorTeamId]') AND visitorTeamId IN ('$_GET[homeTeamId]', 
       '$_GET[visitorTeamId]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL operators have an *order of precedence*. What that means is that some operators are evaluated before others.

We can use parenthesis to specify the order we want operators evaluated, to override the default order.

Consider:

```
 SELECT '0 AND 1 OR 1'   AS cond, 0 AND 1 OR 1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '(0 AND 1) OR 1' AS cond, (0 AND 1) OR 1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '0 AND (1 OR 1)' AS cond, 0 AND (1 OR 1)
```

returns:

```
cond            0 AND 1 OR 1  
--------------  ------------
 0 AND 1 OR 1               1
 (0 AND 1) OR 1             1
 0 AND (1 OR 1)             0
```